# Update web page using JavaScript without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to figure out how to update part of a web page using JavaScript when a user changes an input field on another part of the same page.  However because I'm using `document.write`, I can't go back later and update this unless I reload the page.  I admit I am not overly competent with JavaScript.  If anyone can give me advice on how to approach this problem it would be most appreciated.  I'm hoping that there's a way to do this without Ajax, as it's just a very simple task and I don't want it to get too complicated.

My site has a 5 step quote calculator that shows and hides divs to go through the steps without loading/reloading the page.  On the last step, step 5, I perform a calculation based on step 1 and output it using document.write.  But because I allow the user to go back to Step 1 and make changes to the input text field, the calculation on step 5 becomes incorrect when they return.

I would like to avoid page reloads since I'm using jQuery to do some cool transition effects you go through the steps.  What's the best way to approach a problem like this?

I would happily do some research on my own but I'm not exactly sure where to start.

Comment: Q: Why are you using document.write()??? STRONG SUGGESTION: Familiarize yourself with a framework (like jQuery, for example).  Worry about the framework, rather than Javascript per se.  Look at a couple of tutorials ... *then* revisit this question.  Do it with a [jQuery handler](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_events.asp); modify the DOM directly (document.write *not* invited ;))

Comment: @paulsm4, thanks for the tip I have spent the last few months learning jQuery and it has changed my life!  It's made so many things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you should bind the calculations on the onchange event of the fields in step 1 so the fields in step 5 are automatically updated.

Example: 
In screen 1:

```
<input type="text" name="inputFromScreen1" id="input1" onchange="calculateResult()">
```

In screen 5:

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

JS:

```
function calculateResult()
{
   //parse the values into float or int otherwise you'll get a concatenated string
   var result=parseInt($("#input1").val())+.....;

   //check if your result is a number
   if (!isNaN(result))
       $("#results").html('<p>'+result+'</p>');
}
```

*Note: I am using JQuery because it makes dom manipulation very easy and is cross browser compatible. Learn more at http://jquery.com/

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for!!  I've learned just enough jQuery for what you posted to make sense as well.  Most appreciated!

Comment: I should add that because the values I was adding together came from a text field, I had to wrap them in the Number() function which I guess casts them as ints/numeric.  Example : var total=Number($("#indoorcameras").val()) + Number($("#outdoorcameras").val());   Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Sure.. you should check the input with parseInt() function or parseFloat()